# How to set ttk calendar programmatically

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I am using [this ttk calendar](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Demo/tkinter/ttk/ttkcalendar.py) in my application.

What I want to do is set the calendar using a `datetime.date` instance so when the calendar appears the specified date is highlighted.

I thought I could go through the `_show_selection` method with manual `text` and `bbox` args.  To test this idea, I placed this line at the end of the `__init__` method:

`self._show_selection('%02d'%16,(42,61,41,20))`

I was hoping it would highlight the 16th of this month (May), but it did not.

I got the args from running `print text, bbox` in the _pressed method.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I am puzzled too.  I put `        print((text, textw, bbox, canvas['background'], x, y,
              canvas['width'], canvas['height'], canvas.text), '\n',
              (self._calendar, canvas.coords(canvas.text),
              canvas.itemcget(canvas.text, 'text')))
` at the end of _show_selection and everything is the same.  I also added `        self._selection = ('16', 'I004', '#2')` before the added call in `__init__`, to match the line in `_pressed`.  I even added  `self._canvas.place_forget(), from looking in _setup_selection.

Comment: I also tries `        self._canvas.event_generate('<ButtonPress-1>', x=50, y=73)
        self._calendar.event_generate('<ButtonPress-1>', x=50, y=73)
`.  I put `        print(evt.x, evt.y, evt.widget)` at the top of `_pressed` to verify that it is called on startup with essentially the same event. Still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part @Oblivion is correct, however I want to be able to use a `Datetime.date` object and to be able to traverse the months and years if needed.  Once I changed the `set_day` method below everything worked perfectly.

```
def set_day(self, dt_object):
    day = dt_object.day
    w = self._calendar

    if not w.winfo_viewable():
        w.after(200, self.set_day, dt_object)
        return
    while dt_object.year < self._date.year:
        self._prev_month()
    while dt_object.year > self._date.year:
        self._next_month()
    while dt_object.month < self._date.month:
        self._prev_month()
    while dt_object.month > self._date.month:
        self._next_month()
    text = '%02d' % day
    column = None
    for iid in self._items:
        rowvals = w.item(iid, 'values')
        try:
            column = rowvals.index(text)
        except ValueError as err:
            pass
        else:
            item = iid
            bbox = w.bbox(iid, column)
            break

    if column is not None:
        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)
    else:
        print "Column is None"
```

Answer (score 0):

In __setup_selection() there is a binding on the Configure event.
Presumably, it's there to remove the "selection canvas" when the calendar
is resized. However, the Configure event also fires when the calendar is
first mapped to screen, so your pre-selected date disappears before you ever
get to see it.

set_day (below) lets you select a day programmatically. It sidesteps the problem of that first Configure event by re-scheduling itself if the widget
is not yet visible.

changes to Calendar:

```
def __setup_selection(self, sel_bg, sel_fg):
    self._font = font.Font()
    self._canvas = canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self._calendar,
        background=sel_bg, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    canvas.text = canvas.create_text(0, 0, fill=sel_fg, anchor='w')

    canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
    #self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', lambda evt: canvas.place_forget())
    self._calendar.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)        
    self._calendar.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self._pressed)

def on_configure(self, event):
    self._canvas.place_forget()
    if self._selection is not None:
        text, iid, column = self._selection
        bbox = self._calendar.bbox(iid, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox)

def _prev_month(self):
    """Updated calendar to show the previous month."""
    self._canvas.place_forget()
    self._selection = None #
    self._date = self._date - self.timedelta(days=1)
    self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
    self._build_calendar() # reconstuct calendar

def _next_month(self):
    """Update calendar to show the next month."""
    self._canvas.place_forget()
    self._selection = None #
    year, month = self._date.year, self._date.month
    self._date = self._date + self.timedelta(
        days=calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] + 1)
    self._date = self.datetime(self._date.year, self._date.month, 1)
    self._build_calendar() # reconstruct calendar

def set_day(self, day):
    w = self._calendar
    if not w.winfo_viewable():
        w.after(200, self.set_day, day)
        return

    text = '%02d' % day
    column = None
    for iid in self._items:
        rowvals = w.item(iid, 'values')
        try:
            column = rowvals.index(text)
        except ValueError as err:
            pass
        else:
            item = iid
            bbox = w.bbox(iid, column)
            break

    if column is not None:
        self._selection = (text, item, column)
        self._show_selection(text, bbox) 

#test
def test():
    import sys
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('Ttk Calendar')
    ttkcal = Calendar(firstweekday=calendar.SUNDAY)
    ttkcal.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

    if 'win' not in sys.platform:
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam')

    ttkcal.set_day(16) #
    root.mainloop()
```